# Pass variables from htaccess to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, .htaccess, shell, cgi

I'm trying to pass the value of a cookie to a bash script:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} mycookie=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* script.sh?cookievar=%1
```

... but can't seem to find out how to read the GET variable in the bash script. (I suppose I'm asking Google the wrong queries, but can't find any info on this).

Is this even possible, and if so, please how?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at `QUERY_STRING` environment variable in Bash in order to access `GET` variables. In your case it should be set to `cookievar=VALUE`. To extract a variable's value, use something like this:

```
COOKIEVAR=$(echo ${QUERY_STRING} | sed -n -e 's/^.*cookievar=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' -e 's/%20/ /g')
```

Good luck!